# Как правильно собрать статическую библиотеку ffmpeg для nano pi

Tags: c++, аудио, cmake, ffmpeg, makefile

Написал приложение на базе ffmpeg 3 и выше. На пишке версия ffmpeg 2.8 в следствии чего вываливаются три ошибки на функции которые не включены в ffmpeg 2.8. Замен этим функциям найти не удалось. Поделитесь каким нибудь мануалом как собрать статический ffmpeg что бы я мог запускать приложение на пишке. Пробовал собрать ffmpeg версии 4 на nano pi библиотеки собрались и версия у них нужная но ошибки все теже как будто я собираю приложение с другой версией ffmpeg.И при вызове ffmpeg выводиться странная версия библиотеки:

```
ffmpeg version N-93467-g5465562 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg 
  developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609
  configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.105 / 58. 47.105
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

Так же приложу cmake файл:

```
project( screamer )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
include (cmake/git_version.cmake)

option( BUILD_DOCS "docs create" off )

git_version()

message( STATUS "\tGit version string: ${GIT_VERSION_STRING}")

# libsoundio cpp wrapper
add_subdirectory( modules/soundiocpp )
# ring buffer library
add_subdirectory( modules/ringbuffer )

find_package( PkgConfig )
pkg_check_modules( DBUS dbus-1 )
include_directories( ${DBUS_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${DBUS_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

find_package( Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

#ncurses pack find
SET(CURSES_USE_NCURSES TRUE)
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

file( GLOB_RECURSE screamer_sources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.[ch]pp )

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${screamer_sources} )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${DBUS_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CURSES_LIBRARIES} soundiocpp ringbuffer pthread )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} avcodec avutil avformat swresample  )
target_compile_definitions( ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC GIT_VERSION_STRING=${GIT_VERSION_STRING} )

message( STATUS "\tGit version string: ${avcodec}")

set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES )
```

Запускаю без каких либо модификаторов. cmake.., make. Может я делаю что то не так.

Comment: А при чем тут этот cmake файл? ffmpeg собирался посредством autotools

Comment: @VTT добавил cmake что бы не было вопрос какую версию я указывал у библиотек. Как тогда такое может быть что система видит одну версии библиотеки а компилятор другой ?